# 4 WAN FAILOVER (DHCP) MIKROTIK RB750Gr3

Tags: networking, router, nat, mikrotik-routeros, failover

I am trying to do Failover with Mikrotik with not success

I currently have a router (LRT224)
I want to change it for (RB750Gr3)
I need to have a backup connection via a mobile network

setting up the RB750Gr3 with a single ISP was simple
however, when I want to configure a failover with four WAN interfaces, the challenge exceeded my knowledge and patience

```
ACTUAL ROUTER: LRT224 Dual WAN Gigabit VPN Router

NEW ROUTER: RB750Gr3
ROUTEROS: 7.10.2

INTERFACES
ETH1-LAN 192.168.1.1/24, LOCAL NETWORK
ETH2-WANDHCP CLIENT, GET PRIVATE IP FROM ISP GATEWAY (FTTH) NAT
ETH3-WANDHCP CLIENT, GET PRIVATE IP FROM ISP GATEWAY (CABLEMODEM) NAT
ETH4-WANDHCP CLIENT, GET PRIVATE IP FROM ISP GATEWAY (LTE ROUTER) NAT
ETH5-WANDHCP CLIENT, GET PRIVATE IP FROM ISP GATEWAY (4G ROUTER) NAT

CONSIDERATIONS
ETH[1-5]-WAN LOCAL LINK ALWAY UP AND LOCAL NEIGHBOUR GATEWAY IP IS UP (192.168.X.1)

LOCAL DHCP SERVER
INTERFACE: ETH1-LAN
IP-POOL: 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.200

FAILOVER (NO LOAD BALANCER)
ORDER: ETH2-WAN -> ETH3-WAN -> ETH4-WAN -> ETH5-WAN
CHECK: TEST INTERNET CONECTION (LOCAL LINK, NEIGHBOUR IP IS ALWAY UP)

PORT FORWARDING
FROM: ANY WAN
PORT: 1234
PROTO: TCP/UDP

TO: 192.168.1.50
PORT: 3389
PROTO: TCP/UDP
```

[image]

[4 WAN FAILOVER (DHCP)](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?p=1017844&hilit=4%20WAN%20FAILOVER%20DHCP)